# Visualizing my own path planner?

Tags: ros, visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have written an Hybrid A* algorithm in C++. I wish to visualize my algorithm on ROS. Can someone please tell what are the steps to be followed to do this....

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36869/visualizing-my-own-path-planner?/) by [nikhilsv92](https://answers.ros.org/users/2658/nikhilsv92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Publish your plans as a [nav_msgs/Path](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/Path.html) message. rviz can directly display that using a plugin.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1